# Regex to match comma in string

Tags: c#, regex

I need a to match a comma in string, this is the example:

> dog:Cat,hi:Bye,num:,1,2,3,5,6,7,8,9,10,this:that

[image]

I want to match ONLY the comma with te green arrow using a regex or something

> The value from "num:" always will be similar. example "num:,4,7,9" or "num:,2"

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should do it:

```
,(?=\w+:)
```

- Regex Demo: http://www.rubular.com/r/pv2lgKTO0m
- C# Code Sample: http://ideone.com/vwX7O